# Image of pink haired girl shooting rainbow gun that creates an image

Tags: story-identification, movie

Looking to find the source of the image. It is actually a short video and the full thing can be seen at [Coub](https://coub.com/view/hk8eb).

[image: Still from the clip]

Comment: My first thought was either Ramona Flowers from *Scott Pilgrim* or Hit-Girl from *Kick-Ass*, but after seeing the .gif she's definitely neither of those.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This clip is part of a longer ad for Battery energy drinks. That's what the alien is drinking, after all:

[image]

You can see what looks to be the full ad [here](https://vimeopro.com/cutsdatflo/anthony-sylvester-reel/video/190907769).

Comment: Did you pause the video in the question and zoom to the drink to get its name?

Comment: @user931 Yes, but the screenshot I took is from the full video, since it's clearer. In any case I knew it had to be an ad as soon as I saw the video linked to in the OP.